# Malformed file warning on boot

Tags: boot, grub2

About 1/3 of the time that I boot my laptop, I get an error message that says

```
Error: Malformed file.
Press any key to continue...
```

I press a key, and then my computer boots up and I can't discern any negative effects.

It's kind of disconcerting, and does delay the boot process.

How do I resolve this error and ensure my system is stable?

Comment: Is that the only error message you get? If yes, any clues in `/var/log/syslog` or in `/var/log/boot.log`?

Comment: @Jobin, that's the only text on screen. I didn't see anything in either log that seemed related. However, `/var/log/syslog` is huge, so maybe I missed it. Is there a command I can run that would help refine a search for anything helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in Grub, see [Launchpad bug #1311247 - error: malformed file, press any key to continue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1311247). The upstream bug report is at [bug #42134: loadenv.c – check_blocklists – algorithm for block overlap check is wrong](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42134). There does not seem to be a reliable workaround - you will just have to wait for it to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of users have this problem, including myself.

Found a piece of text that solved the issue for me and hopefully others as well.

edit `/etc/default/grub` and add:

```
# If you want to enable the save default function, uncomment the following
# line, and set GRUB_DEFAULT to saved.
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

After saving the file update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Re-start the computer and the issue might be gone :-)

Recently I found out that ACPI settings in the BIOS may also cause "malformed file" message during boot. My computer does not shut down completely and therefore I was messing around with the ACPI settings. It is interesting to see that this warning has multiple root causes

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running Linux Mint 17 with 3.14.5-031405-lowlatency kernel.  I installed this kernel to fix slow wireless issues.

I started noticing this same issue just a few days ago.  I hit any key and it boots up fine.

The fix for me was to completely remove all of the old kernels (stock that came with Mint 17).  I then performed a dist-upgrade, rebooted and am not getting the message any more.

I am not a linux guru so can't explain why this worked, just went on a hunch.