# Error: Malformed File on boot. How to get rid of it?

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, shutdown, ubuntu-gnome

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 LTS on my computer and it shows this error like, maybe 2 out of 3 times I start the computer. It has no negative effect AFAIK except for increasing the startup time. This has been bugging me for the past week and I really want to get rid of it. Can someone help me with that?

**Side note:** Maybe this is unrelated, but I noticed that when I shutdown the computer, it takes not more than 4 seconds to power down and that makes me suspect that it does not shutdown correctly.

This is the error message

> Error: Malformed file.
>
> Press any key to continue...

Answer (score 2):

This bug was fixed in the package [grub2 - 2.02~beta2-21](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/2.02~beta2-21)

Builds are as of this writing available only for Vivid but may work for 14.04 as well or as an alternative you could compile from source.

Sources:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1311247

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/2.02~beta2-21

Answer (score 1):

This is a reported [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1311247). Although there are some temporary solutions posted in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1311247) there seems to be no permanent fix available. See [Malformed file warning on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473230/malformed-file-warning-on-boot) for one suggested fix.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I think it does: "Q: Can someone help me with that" A: no permanent fix.

Comment: So it is a comment.

Comment: I disagree. Should all bug related answers should be comments? AFAIK, as of 2015-04-15 it is still a bug and that is the answer. probable' fixes are given in those links

Comment: @Pilot6 I must agree with Ron: *"No, this is impossible"* is a perfectly reasonable answer...  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Do you know how many my answers have been closed because of same reason? :-) But then the question should be flagged as off topic. It is a bug.

Comment: @Pilot6: Ping me in [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) on this...

Comment: "This is a bug (link to bug)" is a valid answer IMO and it's one I've given before. Launchpad is a stable link destination so doesn't quite tick all the criteria that make "link only answers" evil... but that said, *this* answer could go further to explain the issue or the workaround. Moreover, if we already have an [exact duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/473230/malformed-file-warning-on-boot) of this problem on the site, why aren't we closing it against that?